# Change iframe src using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have three different pages; `player_lo.html`, `player_hi.html` and `player_med.html`.

These three pages are different quality flow player stream pages. I want to use JavaScript to change an `iframe`'s source.

I have this script but it doesn't work:

```
<a href="/player/player_lo.html" class="button grey" onclick="$('#player').attr('src', 'player_lo.html'); $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('red'); $(this).parent().find('a').addClass('grey'); $(this).addClass('red').removeClass('grey'); return false;">Low Quality</a>
<a href="/player/player_med.html" class="button red" onclick="$('#player').attr('src', 'player_med.html'); $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('red'); $(this).parent().find('a').addClass('grey'); $(this).addClass('red').removeClass('grey'); return false;">medium quality</a>
<a href="/player/player_hi.html" class="button grey" onclick="$('#player').attr('src', 'player_hi.html'); $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('red'); $(this).parent().find('a').addClass('grey'); $(this).addClass('red').removeClass('grey'); return false;">high quality/a>
```

For an example of what I'm trying to do, look at this: http://slon.ru/tvrain/ 
When you click on Низкое качество - it's another frame, if next, another etc...

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it's player in Iframe, @DarkXphenomenon nothing, i have iframe also, <iframe id="player" src="#player" frameborder="0" width="568" height="320" scrolling="no"></iframe>
It should be change quality (sources) when i click

Comment: You can try to use target="iframe_name" in your links, that might work.

Comment: Can you give me more information what to do?:) i am new in JS:) @Angel

Comment: I am not sure this is what you are looking for or if it will fix the problem you have. What I was saying is to put a name for the iframe, like: name="player_iframe". And in every link just add this: target="player_iframe". That sets the target for the link href to be loaded into the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You're using absolute paths in the `href` of your links (e.g. `"/player/player_lo.html"`), but relative paths in you JavaScript (e.g. `'player_lo.html'`). This might be your problem.

- Try using the same (absolute) paths in your JavaScript.
- Make sure the pages actually exist.
- Keep an eye on your browser's error console to see what is going wrong.

Other tips you might find helpful:

Instead of two classes called **red** and **grey** (which are mutually exclusive classes, meaning a button can't be both at the same time), try using a single class which describes the difference, e.g. **active**. Then, use CSS to style buttons to be grey by default, or red when they have the class `active`. Added advantage is that the colours are not encoded in the class names (e.g. you can change the active color to blue, or whatever, in the future).

Also, instead of using the inline `onclick` attribute, try binding the event hander to the `<a>` tags [from JavaScript itself](http://api.jquery.com/click/). That way, you can easily use the `<a>`'s existing `href`, plus you can reuse the code needed to make the clicked button active.

HTML:

```html
<a href="/player/player_lo.html" class="button">Low Quality</a>
<a href="/player/player_med.html" class="button">medium quality</a>
<a href="/player/player_hi.html" class="button">high quality/a>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    var button = $(this);
    $('#player').attr('src', button.attr('href'));
    makeActive(button);
    return false;
});

function makeActive(button) {
    $('.button').removeClass('active');
    button.addClass('active');
}
```

CSS:

```css
.button {
    color: grey;
}
.button.active {
    color: red;
}
```

Documentation:

- [jQuery .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)